# Calling same js function on pageload and on button click and displaying both functions called

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function and I want to call the same function twice.
       Once on page load and once on a button click.
       I want the output as the function on page load will keep on running in backend and
       display output and when button is clicked again function is called and its output 
       gets displayed.
       Finally both functions output should be displayed.
       This is what I have written but am not getting the output.

For e.g.

Javascript file: n.js

```
function webservice{

   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
      alert("some msg");
      `enter code here`
   }
```

html file n.html

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script type = "text/javascript" src="n.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

   window.onload=function() {
   webservice();
   }


   </script>
   </head>

   <body>

   <input id="button"  type = "button" name = "webservice" value = "Call Webservice"      
   onClick="webservice()" />
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: An `alert()` in a `for` loop... Do you get an JS error? Is ``enter code here`` actually in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code is working on my machine. I think you are missing `()` for function webservice(). so instead of `webservice` use `webservice()`

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function webservice()
{
   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
      alert("some msg");
   }
}
window.onload=function()
{
   webservice();
}
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input id="webservice"  type = "button" name = "webservice" value = "Call Webservice" onClick="webservice()" />
</body>
</html>
```

**Update:**

if you write your `onload` function like this then you will be able to execute `call 1` and `call 2`, but`call 2` will begin when `call 1` loop is completed.

```
window.onload=function()
{
   webservice('onload');    //call 1 
   document.getElementById("webservice").click();  //call 2 
}
```

Comment: I am getting the output after using webservice() in function but the onclick function overrides the onload function.

Comment: So i am only getting the output for onclick function whereas I want the final output of both the functions i.e getting alert 20 times. 10 for onload and 10 for onclick

Comment: Thanks for everyone's efforts

Comment: @user2168945 have you checked my example in the answer, it gives alert for 20 times - 10 for onload and 10 for onclick

Comment: Thank you very much Bhushan for your code. It is working and displaying msg 20 times but what exaclty I want is when the onload for loop is getting displayed at same time if I click button then onclick for loop also should get executed. i.e if 4 loops of onload get executed and I click button onclick for loop should start and simultaneously onload also should continue from 5th loop.

Comment: @user2168945 when onload alerts are displayed, then how can you click on the `button`? first you will need to say `ok` to all `10 alerts` then the browser will allow you to click on button.

Comment: @user2168945 see update, in which i have click the button on `onload` event

Answer (score 0):

I think you code may be in wrong format.

```
function webservice{
                for(i=0;i<10;i++)
                     {
                     alert("some msg");
                 `enter code here`
                 }
```

change to

```
function webservice(){
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
          alert("some msg");
       //enter code here
      }
```

just add () after webservice. like webservice().